# svg image with a clip-path, animating scale or width

Tags: css, animation, svg, transition, clip-path

I have an image clipped by a clip path in an svg:

http://codepen.io/mjjwatson/pen/GopNaj

I have rigged up this pen to toggle a zoomed class on the image every four seconds. There's a transition on the width so I would expect the image to animate it's width from 42% to 100% while the clip-path remains the same, creating an image zooming effect. However, in Chrome it appears to glitch refreshing- if you resize the browser you can see the width changing, but not animating.

I've also tried transform scaling the image:

```
image { transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1); }
```

This scales the image and does animate as desired, although it also scales the clip-path.

Is there another solution to achieve this image zooming effect while keeping the clip-path in place, or should I rethink things?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrWKbR ?

Comment: You could move the clip-path to the parent `<g>` element but Chrome appears not to render the animation properly if you do that.

Comment: @NenadVracar no, I'm not, as that animates the clip-path too. The intention is to animate the image, but not the clip-path.

Comment: That said, actually a combo of what @RobertLongson and Nenad have answered works, putting the scale property on the image, but the clip-path on the group! Awesome. I'll answer this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combo of Robert Longson and Nenad Vracar's comments helped with this solution.

We can put the transform scale property onto the image, while putting the clippath onto the group element, as seen on this codepen fork:

http://codepen.io/mjjwatson/pen/eJpgJx

```
   <g class="slideshow" data-speed="1000" clip-path="url(#mask-1)">

        <image class="slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" x="0"  height="100%"  width="42%" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/900/500/abstract/1" />

    </g>
```